# math behind normal compression

Tags: math, vector, compression

below codes(rewritten by C#) are used to compress unit normal vector from [Wild Magic 5.17](https://www.geometrictools.com/Downloads/Downloads.html),could someone explain some math behind them or share some related refs ? *I can figure out the octant bits setting, but the mantissa packing and unpacking seem complex ...*

[codes gist](https://gist.github.com/tkokof/b05a8e794a5200abbba9ff13e1b4f98d)

some of codes here

```
// ...

public static ushort CompressNormal(Vector3 normal)
{
    var x = normal.x;
    var y = normal.y;
    var z = normal.z;
    Debug.Assert(MathUtil.IsSame(x * x + y * y + z * z, 1));

    // Determine octant.
    ushort index = 0;

    if (x < 0.0)
    {
        index |= 0x8000;
        x = -x;
    }
    if (y < 0.0)
    {
        index |= 0x4000;
        y = -y;
    }
    if (z < 0.0)
    {
        index |= 0x2000;
        z = -z;
    }

    // Determine mantissa.
    ushort usX = (ushort)Mathf.Floor(gsFactor * x);
    ushort usY = (ushort)Mathf.Floor(gsFactor * y);
    ushort mantissa = (ushort)(usX + ((usY * (255 - usY)) >> 1));
    index |= mantissa;

    return index;
}

// ...
```

Comment: Author has chosen some method to store approximations of two (implicitly three due to unit length)  float values in 13 bits and later retrieve them. It is asymmetric (squeezing of z,x.and y components are different). Do you expect some sacral knowledge in this approach?

Comment: yes,I'm curious about the math behind the approximate method ~

Comment: could you share some related refs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked Mr. Eberly (author of Wild Magic) and he gives the ref, desc in short, codes above try to map (x, y) to an index of triangular array (index is from 0 to N * (N + 1) / 2 - 1)

[image]

more details are in the related [doc](https://github.com/tkokof/Resources/blob/master/WildMagic/CompressedUnitVectors.pdf) here,
btw, another solution [here](https://oroboro.com/compressed-unit-vectors/) with a different compress method.

Answer (score 0):

Author wanted to use 13 bits.
Trivial way: *6 bits for x component + 6 bits for* y - occupies only 12 bits, so he invented approach to assign ~90 (lsb) units for x and  and ~90 (msb) units for y (90*90~2^13).

I have no idea why he uses quadratic formula for y-component - this way gives slightly different distribution of approximated values between smaller and larger values - but why specifically for y?